# Skipping cells in excel for averaging

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to take the average of some cells in excel. I need to go M2&M3, M4&M5, M6&M7 etc. No matter how many time i try, excel wants to do M2&M3 then M3&M4 then M4&M5 etc. Even when I manually make the first few cells the correct way, it doesnt seem to catch on. I have over 250 data points, so manual entry would be tedious. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your average function in N2 `=average(M2:M3)` and N4 `=average(M4:M5)`. Highlight N2 to N5 (two values and two blanks). Then drag your formula down to extend the series. Excel will know to skip every other row and fill in the averages where you want them.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX to set the pattern range:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(M:M,ROW(1:1)*2):INDEX(M:M,ROW(1:1)*2+1))
```

This will skip every other line when dragged down

[image]